# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' For While Loop

Tags: php, while-loop

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result): ?>
<div class="box">

    <h3><?php htmlspecialchars($row['testi_name'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></h3>
    <?php htmlspecialchars($row['testi_content'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I used : for my while loop but for some reason it display `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'`
May i know what causes this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket after `($result)`, correct representation should be as below

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
```